# Comment box disappearing when clicking "Like"

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-fbml

I have a Like button on my web site which I generated using this link:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

The code for my button looks like this:

```
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $mylink; ?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

For an unknown reason the comment box which is supposed to appear when I click "Like" disappears right after clicking "Like" and a "Confirm" link appears instead.

Thank you, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is an anti-spam and/or clickjacking measure and can sometimes be triggered on a new site by frequent liking and unliking of a page or users marking it as spam

When users confirm that they did intend to like your page the Like goes through as normal, and after a while the protection is removed and the comments box works without the confirmation step required